# D3.js div blocks mouseover event in svg

Tags: d3.js

If I create a simple scatter plot using d3.js, I can record the `mouseover` events on the circle elements by printing 'hey' to the console:

http://jsfiddle.net/pkerpedjiev/opmhaz0n/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<div class="chart" style="position: aboslute; left: 0px: top: 0px; width: 300px; height: 200px;" ></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var xVals = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42,72];
    var yVals = [13, 49, 34, 2, 22, 23, 44];

    var data = xVals.map(function(d,i) { return [d, yVals[i]]; });

    var width=300;
    var height=200;

    console.log('data:', data);

    /*
    var div = d3.select(".chart").append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("width", width + "px")
    .style("height", height + "px")
    .style("left", 0 + "px")
    .style("top", 0  + "px")
    .style("opacity", 0.2);
    */ 

    var svg = d3.select(".chart")
    .append("svg")

    svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d[0]; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d[1]; })
    .attr('r', 4)
    .attr('fill', 'black')
    .on('mouseover', function(d) { console.log('hey'); });

</script>
```

If I add a div behind the svg, however, the `mouseover` event doesn't get recorded:

http://jsfiddle.net/pkerpedjiev/Lxgbycr8/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<div class="chart" style="position: aboslute; left: 0px: top: 0px; width: 300px; height: 200px;" ></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var xVals = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42,72];
    var yVals = [13, 49, 34, 2, 22, 23, 44];

    var data = xVals.map(function(d,i) { return [d, yVals[i]]; });

    var width=300;
    var height=200;

    console.log('data:', data);

    var div = d3.select(".chart").append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("width", width + "px")
    .style("height", height + "px")
    .style("left", 0 + "px")
    .style("top", 0  + "px")
    .style("opacity", 0.2);

    var svg = d3.select(".chart")
    .append("svg")

    svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d[0]; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d[1]; })
    .attr('r', 4)
    .attr('fill', 'black')
    .on('mouseover', function(d) { console.log('hey'); });

</script>
```

Is there a way to register the 'mouseover' event when there's a div in the background behind the svg?

Comment: Yes, set `pointer-events` to `none`: http://jsfiddle.net/Lxgbycr8/2/

Comment: Thanks! And what if I also want to receive pointer events in the background div? Will this affect that?

Comment: Yes, you won't get any pointer events this way -- if you want both to receive events, put the `div` in the background.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but what do you mean by put it in the background? Isn't it already behind the svg?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean -- the positioning is interfering with that, if you set `position` to `absolute` on the SVG as well it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Lxgbycr8/3/

Comment: Hey thanks Lars! That seems to work just fine! But now if I have a 'click' handler below the svg, it doesn't register the 'click' in the div: http://jsfiddle.net/pkerpedjiev/omx9mpqh/1/

Comment: You may have to set `pointer-events` to `none` on the SVG and to `all` on the circles.

Comment: Thanks! That works! If you want to formulate it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positioning of the elements is interfering with what you may expect for mouse events here, in particular you need to set `position` to `absolute` for the SVG as well to make it appear in front of the `div`.

If you want the SVG to "catch" events only on certain elements, set `pointer-events` to `none` on the SVG and to `all` on the elements you want to receive the events.